# How to generate Access Token for FB single sign on login?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using javascript in web application and trying to implement Facebook single sign on login. How do i exactly generate Access token ?? I used :`var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;`, but everytime different users login, it gives the same Access token..

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the end user through the oauth authorization process, as the end result you will get an access token to use.

See:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/